# GruntJS how to pass a obect argument to grunt.task.run()

Tags: javascript, node.js, config, gruntjs

I have some problem when I pass only string to grunt.task.run() that will work as follow

```
grunt.registerTask('buildAll', function() {
  ['url-1', 'url-2'].forEach(function(config) {
    grunt.task.run('updateConfig:'+ config, 'requirejs');
  });
});

grunt.registerTask('updateConfig', function(config) {
  // console.log(config);
  grunt.config('requirejs.compile.options.baseUrl', config);
  // console.log(grunt.config('requirejs.compile.options'));
});
```

but when I pass a object like {name:'a', baseUrl: 'path2'} will get undefine the code as follow :

```
grunt.registerTask('buildAll', function() {
  [{name:'main-1', baseUrl:'./path1/'}, {name:'main-2', baseUrl:'./path2/'}].forEach(function(config) {
    grunt.task.run('updateConfig:'+ config, 'requirejs');
  });
});

grunt.registerTask('updateConfig', function(config) {
  // console.log(config);
  grunt.config('requirejs.compile.options.baseUrl', config.baseUrl);
  grunt.config('requirejs.compile.options.name', config.name);
  // console.log(grunt.config('requirejs.compile.options'));
});
```

any solution for it. I need build mutlpile requirejs main for a project and the config is very different?